# How do I parse(and then find particular) XML data received from an API request?

Tags: java, xml, api

I am almost a complete beginner regarding XML, as well as having only very basic knowledge about Java. I have tried looking up many things the past day and trying many code snippets but have not yet found a solution, so I don't know if my search terms are wrong, or I'm just too confused.

I have this URL(http://www.example.com/api/WebAPI/?dataset=wanted_dataset&keyref=12345) to get XML data from and it returns:

```
<channel>
  <title>PSI Update</title>
  <source>Airviro</source>
 <item>
   <region>...</region>
   <region>...</region>
   <region>...</region>
   <region>
     <id>rEA</id>
     <latitude>1.35735</latitude>
     <longitude>103.94000</longitude>
     <record timestamp="20160210160000">
       <reading type="NPSI" value="57"/>
       <reading type="NPSI_PM25_3HR" value="56"/>
       <reading type="NO2_1HR_MAX" value="5"/>
       <reading type="PM10_24HR" value="32"/>
       <reading type="PM25_24HR" value="18"/>
       <reading type="SO2_24HR" value="4"/>
       <reading type="CO_8HR_MAX" value="0.53"/>
       <reading type="O3_8HR_MAX" value="31"/>
       <reading type="NPSI_CO" value="5"/>
       <reading type="NPSI_O3" value="13"/>
       <reading type="NPSI_PM10" value="32"/>
       <reading type="NPSI_PM25" value="57"/>
       <reading type="NPSI_SO2" value="2"/>
   </record>
 </region>
<region>...</region>
<region>...</region>
```

And this is my code so far:

```
public class HazeCheck {

    public void getHazeLevel() throws Exception{            
        URL myUrl = new URL("http://www.example.com/api/WebAPI/?dataset=wanted_dataset&keyref=12345");
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(myUrl.openStream());
        XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("I have no idea what I should put here");
        String npsiValue = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING).toString();
        System.out.println("NPSI: " + npsiValue );
    }
}
```

I'm trying to display the value inside [reading type="NPSI" value="57"] on the console.

I'm really sorry if any similar questions have been posted before, but I've looked through at least 20 different results but did not manage to understand or find a solution. It would be greatly appreciated if you could use idiot-proof explanations. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/ yet?

Comment: Yes, I did, but I didn't manage to gleam much from it. Is there any particular area of the above document that would help? I'll go look over it again just to be sure.

Comment: It may help to read https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/ first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The w3c-specs are not always that easy to understand. A more simple explanation is to be found here [Ten minute XPath tutorial](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/perl/excerpts/system-admin-with-perl/ten-minute-xpath-utorial.html)

If you want to try your expression you can do it here: http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath

For example

```
/channel/item/region/record/reading[@type='NPSI_SO2']/@value
```

will give you **2** as a result.